# Basic Azure DevOps flow for ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a standard way of working for building and deploying my asp .net applications on a build server (usually Jenkins). I have a custom build script and publish profile that builds my solution, copies some files and publishes the web project all with a single call to MSBuild.

I am trying to recreate this in Azure DevOps. My first obstacle seems to be that build and "publish" (or "release" in DevOps parlance) are separate steps. But it also seems like maybe I don't need to "publish"?

So

1. How do I control what ends up in the "artifacts" folder of the build? Is that through Azure? Can I do it with a .MSBuild file? And
2. Do I even need the concept of "publish" or does the release step just copy all artifacts to the destination (a VM in this case)? Can I control what gets deployed?

I am having a hard time finding some kind of basic tutorial that cover asp .net projects being deployed this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How do I control what ends up in the "artifacts" folder of the build? Is that through Azure? Can I do it with a .MSBuild file?

Yes, we could use the MSBuild Arguments parameter `/p:PackageLocation=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` to control what ends up in the "artifacts" folder.

When we use the task Visual Studio build to build the project, we could edit the MSBuild Arguments parameter to be like: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Test /p:PackageLocation=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

Then we could use [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines, TFS, or a file share.

> 2. Do I even need the concept of "publish" or does the release step just copy all artifacts to the destination (a VM in this case)? Can I control what gets deployed?

Yes, you can simply understand the release step just copy artifacts to the destination. If you want to control what gets deployed, you can filter the artifacts when you use the [copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) with contents.

Check the article [Deploying Web Applications Using Team Build and Release Management](https://colinsalmcorner.com/post/end-to-end-walkthrough-deploying-web-applications-using-team-build-and-release-management) for the details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have existing scripts that work, just use those :). The new YAML builds are moving slowly away from fully featured UI tasks with lots of logic to more bare bones scripts that do what is needed.

It is a common practice though to split build from publish. That way you can put in additional checks, reviews and approvers on the release stage.

In your case it would mean:

- Build stage

  - Use MsBuild to build & create a publish package either in the form of a folder or a zip file.
  - Use the Publish Pipeline Artifact task to store this folder or zip file
- Release stage

  - Use the Download Pipeline Artifact task to restore the file to publish
  - Optionally use a Infra as Code tool to prep the target environment.
  - Use msdeploy.exe or another tool to publish the package. Optionally generate and pass in a settings file to override certain settings.

This way you can have multiple release stages to generate test environments, temporary POC environments etc by simply using another set of variables and/or settings override file.

There are special tasks in Azure Pipelines that wrap around these tools and provide an easy to use UI and some additional logic. These can be very useful if you don't have intimate knowledge of the commandline tools. If you do know your way around them, there may not be a very strong reason to use the fancy tasks.